# enforce Resource Annotation for implementation of abstract val

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a class with an abstract value that is annotated with @StringRes:

```
@get: StringRes
abstract val foo : Int
```

Unfortunately when I pass a non StringRes to that value in the implementation like this:

```
override val foo = 2
```

it still compiles fine - but I want it to throw a compile time error.

The only workaround I found so far is using a function instead of a val - so this fails fine at compile time:

```
@StringRes
abstract fun bar() : Int
```

and

```
override fun bar() = 1
```

But I would like to use a val in this case. Anyone knows how to do it with a val?

Answer (score 1):

`@get` is property getter, so when you will use Kotlin's property getter:

```
var <propertyName>[: <PropertyType>] [= <property_initializer>]
    [<getter>]
    [<setter>]
```

like so:

```
abstract class Hello {
    @get :StringRes
    abstract val foo: Int
}

class World : Hello() {
    override val foo: Int
        get() = 123
}
```

it will generate compile time error.

Comment: Thanks! This is nice already - but with this I would still need to use the function to really enforce usage of a StringRes - so I will wait a bit with accepting - maybe someone has another solution that really enforces it. So just upvoted for now.